# Msf and exploitdb on Backtrack 5

Tags: exploit, tools, metasploit, kali-linux

Metasploit (msf) doesn't see exploits from exploitdb. I've just updated directory on my Backtrack

```
cd /pentest/exploits/exploitdb
svn update
```

How can I load them now into msf? When i use a script `searchsploit <name>` I can find what I need, but I don't know how to load it inside msf.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to be using `msfupdate`?

Comment: Maybe it would. I just thought I can load exploit from that dir.

Answer (score 2):

Metasploit develop their own exploit database. You **cannot** simply load a random exploit from ExploitDB into Metasploit.

Comment: Are you sure, that I cannot load exploits from that directory into metasploit? Can I use them in any other tool? I'm just exploring backtrack and I can't find docs about that exploits...

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure ExploitDB exploits cannot be used in Metasploit (unless the Exploit is specifically developped for Metasploit framework).

Answer (score 1):

In short, doing an 'msfupdate' will get you the latest Metasploit-compatible exploits. The developers do a good job of including modules from 3rd parties, so it's safe to say that this will get you most of the public modules.

As other posters have indicated, Metasploit requires a specific format to utilize an exploit. Metasploit exploits are often (always?) posted on ExploitDB, but are almost always included in the framework itself as well, so loading an exploit from ExploitDB using the 'loadpath' command won't do much good.

Any exploit is theoretically Metasploit compatible, but will need to be ported. This is a decent place to start: https://community.rapid7.com/docs/DOC-1275

There are some beginnings of public 'exploit packs' for metasploit, check out Mubix's 'q' if you're interested: https://github.com/mubix/q - Though these modules are often incomplete or broken for various reasons, much like the 'unstable' branch of the metasploit-framework: https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/tree/unstable/unstable-modules